# Terminal stop launching in Double Commander after Catalina 10.15.1 upgrade

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, catalina

I just upgraded to Catalina 10.15.1 and having some issues opening Terminal from [Double Commander](https://doublecmd.sourceforge.io/)

If i click the terminal button that corresponds to this actions:
[image]

Now the Terminal just wont show, just nothing happens.

If I press `shift+enter` that suppose to open terminal in the current dir I've got this error

```
/var/tmp/doublecmd-Xwwn: line 5: /Users/A/.yarn: is a directory
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
```

[image: Dec-03-2019-11-39-37.gif]

`F9` does not work either (no terminal shown).
I am on DC 0.9.6 beta [Mac OS X >= 10.11, 64 bit, doublecmd-0.9.6-9018.cocoa.x86_64.zip](https://sourceforge.net/p/doublecmd/wiki/Download/).

Any ideas?

**P.S:**
In Catalina they've changed the default shell https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT208050 may be it is something to do with that?

**UPDATE:**
Just created a custom toolbar action that solved my problem, will stick to that for now:

[image]

Comment: Are there options other than cm_RunTerm you could select?

Comment: @bmike `cm_RunTerm` is there by default, yeah there is the whole list of other actions, just picked `cm_Rename` and `cm_About` for a test  - so can confirm that other commands works fine

Comment: I wonder if external command `/bin/bash` or  `/bin/zsh` would get you a shell?

Comment: In my opinion it's a faulty terminal.sh in *../Double Commander/Contents/MacOS/scripts/*! It creates a temp script which should be executed (`cd to selected dir`) in a new? Terminal window and removes itself afterwards. The jump to dir is ommited...

Comment: @klanomath that’s got to be the answer

Comment: @bmike The temporary script is created properly in /var/tmp/ & containing the `cd to selected dir` line but the spawned? Terminal window tries to `cd` to the temp script itself (in my environment) which fails because it's no directory. In *Kuncevic'* env it's slightly different. I tried to fix terminal.sh to no avail.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue. Solution that worked for me:

1. In DC go to Configuration -> Options -> Terminal
2. In section "Command for just running terminal:" was Command `/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app`
3. Rewrite it to the `/System/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app`
4. Save changes and now when you press `Fn + F9` terminal will open in current directory just like before

Comment: Thanks, this worked with DC 1.1.10 on macOs 14.3.1